# First time posting. What exactly is this mean or what it supposed to do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping

I am starting to learn programming so take it easy on me. Can you explain like I am five? Here is the code from LTPHW:

```
for  i  in [ "/", "-", "|", "\\",  "|" ]:
    print "%s \r" % i ,
```

I am getting errors that I could not understand. Is it supposed to print out

```
/, -, |, \\, |
```

What is going on here?

Comment: What kind of error do you get ?

Comment: You should post the full Traceback error you received or else a description of what didn't work. Looking at this I believe it may print nothing as you use a linefeed character at the end of the lines. If you switch it to a newline `\n` you should see each list entry on a separate line.

Comment: this code works in python2

Comment: It's a little unconventional to use `i` for something that isn't numeric. Renaming it to `s` or `string` or `pattern` might boost readability and help you understand it.

Comment: yes I am pretty sure using Python 2.

Comment: has no issue on [ideone](https://ideone.com/DjccQY). Although it's perhaps not always a representative console environment.

Comment: OMG. Forgive me people. I totally messed it has while True at the beggining so code is : while True:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the problem is that that code doesn't have any visible output.

```
>>> for  i  in [ "/", "-", "|", "\\",  "|" ]:
...     print "%s \r" % i ,
...
>>>
```

The root cause is that [LPTHW is terrible](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints).

For each character in the list, this prints that character, then a space, then goes back to the beginning of the line, then prints a space. That last space after going back to the beginning of the line overwrites the written character.

Now, it *looks* like it's trying to do something like a spinning bar animation. You could start messing around with `sys.stdout.write`, but it's easiest to just move to Python 3 (LPTHW still insists on Python 2 for some reason). You should also add a call to `time.sleep` so you can actually *see* the animation. Also, you don't need to create a list of single-character strings; just use a multi-character string:

```
import time

for i in '/-|\\|':
    print(i, end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: thank you so much Tigerhawk. Genius. I messed it up my post, it supposed to have: While True at the beggining and Yes it does showing spinning bar animation lol I thought its en error that loops forever or something...